# auth/invalid-custom-token error when trying to validate user session

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have email and password authentication enabled via firebase on my server. After successfully signing in the user with `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, I'm attempting to validate the user's session by sending the user's token back to the Firebase auth server as a cookie. However, the token always shows up as invalid, even if I do the validation right after signing in (so there's no way the cookie could already be expired.

This is what I'm doing on the backend:

```js
const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  auth,
  email, /* received from client */
  password /* received from client */
);
```

Then I get the token:

```
  const userToken = await userCredential.user.getIdToken(true);
```

and finally I verify the user session

```
  await signInWithCustomToken(auth, userToken);
  /* Send userToken back to client */
```

But no matter what, the final step always fails with `auth/invalid-custom-token`.

Comment: I think I might not be using the right package. I am importing everything from `firebase` but that may in fact just be the client, not server setup.

I want to set everything up in a somewhat traditional way so that user creation and everything is done via the server.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to use the Firebase Client SDK from a server.   It rarely makes sense for a "server" to "log in as a user".

Typically a server would use the Firebase Admin SDK where your server's code bypasses the need to authenticate as a user (it instead becomes "privileged" with the use of a Service Account).  In privileged mode your server code (code that you trust) has the ability to administer your Firebase project and the data within its services.  Privileged mode bypasses Firebase Security Rules (RTDB, Firestore, Storage).

Comment: So all authentication needs to happen on the client? And what if I want an endpoint that can do things that I don’t want to happen on the client, like access a field in another database that is only visible by a given user?

Comment: I recommend that you read up on the purpose of the Client SDK and the Admin SDK.  You want to think through what a "server" means.  Having a "server" authenticate as a user rarely makes sense...and what happens if/when you change authentication configuration (e.g. add 2-factor auth, enable phone-auth, enable social logins (Google, Facebook, GitHub, etc..)) because your "server" won't be able to authenticate for a given user in that scenario.  Also, do you really want to run your own server? Firebase is "serverless". Maybe Cloud Functions would be a better fit for your "server" needs?

Comment: Consider joining a discussion forum with focus on Firebase.  There is the [Firebase Community workspace](https://firebase.community/) on Slack, and the [Firebase Me server](https://firebase.me) on Discord.

Comment: Thank you. I think I “get it” now. If I want to do anything on the backend I have to call a cloud function directly from the client, not from my external controller set up. So I can’t have my cake and eat it too—if I want to do things with my firebase account, I must do it within the walled garden (or have the cloud function call my controller). I guess that makes things easier from a design standpoint anyway.

Comment: No, there is not restriction...no "walled garden".  You can run your own external system if you decide to.  You can run a gasoline-powered car using coal, if you want to.  It just happens to be easier to run it on gasoline. Firebase is a configuration of a set of GCP services such that those services are integrated together "out of the box".  But nothing says you are required to use any or all of those services....it is just typically easier/faster/cheaper to use those services rather than other ones.  But you are welcome to pick-and-choose as you so desire.

Comment: Just because I can throw things over the wall doesn’t make it less of a wall. But yeah I see this isn’t the way to do things.